# How does UnionFS work?

Tags: linux

I have come across various articles as well as an explanation on Wikipedia however am having a hard time understanding what it means. So far I understand that UnionFS is a module that provides a union view of directories. It resides a a layer above the directories which are mounted. UnionFS does not have a mount point.

What confuses me is how does UnionFS know what should be shown in a unified manner?

Comment: Isn't that covered by the wikipedia article? *When mounting branches, the priority of one branch over the other is specified. So when both branches contain a file with the same name, one gets priority over the other.*

Comment: @Caspar - Yes it is however I would like to understand how it unifies directories and gives precedence to one over another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UnionFS works at a directory level, as opposed to a device level, so it dosen't have a mount point - it sits over existing mount points each of which might be a branch - for example, having a base layer (or to use proper terminology - a low precedence layer with the root filesystem) on a read only iso9660 cd rom file system, and a branch on a ramdisk. Each branch is assigned a precedence and a branch with a higher precedence overrides one of a lower precedence.

If a directory exists in two underlying branches, the contents and attributes of the Unionfs directory are the combination of the two lower directories.

If a file exists in two branches, the contents and attributes of the Unionfs file are the same as the file in the higher-priority branch, and the file in the lower-priority branch is ignored.

Finally if there's a duplicate, the duplicate directory is hidden to simplify things.

Linuxjournal [has a fairly comprehensive writeup](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7714) on how unionfs works, if you want something more than a simplified explanation of it

Comment: Thanks. I did read the article on LinuxJournal but what confused me was how does this work with say a Linux LiveCD and a base installation of say Windows. Also what do you mean by a `base layer` and `a branch on ramdisk`?

Comment: clarified base layer. A ramdisk is simply a disk image or a special filesystem entirely run on ram.

Comment: @Journerman Geek - When you say `a low precedence layer with the root filesystem` do you mean any directory below \?

Comment: @Journerman Geek - I came across this article at LWN `http://lwn.net/Articles/217084/` and from what I understand a UnionFS is managed manually not automatically i.e. an administrator would have to create it as opposed to it being dynamically created.

Comment: Can I use unionfs as an overlay over an existing directory, where using that directory as mount point?. For example, I have `dir1` with some files and `dir2` with some another files, Can I use files of `dir2` to appear under `dir1` without just these 2 directories?

Answer (score 1):

Its VFS operations are small stubs that call back into the VFS layer of the underlying filesystems. So when you e.g. read a directory, it reads the directories of the underlying filesystems and merges the file lists.

Comment: [Virtual File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) ([in Linux](http://www.science.unitn.it/~fiorella/guidelinux/tlk/node102.html))

Comment: Thanks. I did finally figure it out but will have a read of what it is because I have no idea of its function.